# CSS correto Div > li > span

Tags: css

Tem uma parte no meu código que não estou conseguindo alterar o css.

```
<div class="AlterarCSS">

<ul>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Tentei alterar assim:

```
.AlterarCSS > li > span{
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: na div que contem o `ul`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O simbolo `>` em um seletor CSS garante que o próximo elemento será um *filho imediato*, e, no seu caso, o filho imediato é o `ul`.

Para obter o resultado esperado, utilize o seguinte seletor:

```css
.AlterarCSS > ul > li > span {
    background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="AlterarCSS">

<ul>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Para mais informações sobre seletores CSS, utilize o [guia de referência  CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 3):

**Seletor filho**

Um seletor filho tem como alvo um filho imediato de um elemento. O seletor filho consiste de um ou mais seletores simples separados por um sinal de maior “>”. O elemento pai fica à esquerda do sinal “>”, e é permitido deixar espaço em branco entre o elemento de combinação e os seletores.

A regra a seguir aplica-se a todos os elementos `strong` que sejam filhos de um elemento div:

```
div > strong { color:#f00; }
```

Somente elementos strong que sejam descendentes diretos do elemento `div` serão afetados por esta regra. Se houver qualquer outro elemento entre o elemento `div` e o elemento `strong` na árvore do documento, o seletor não se aplicará. No exemplo a seguir, somente “Texto um ” será afetado pela regra:

```
<div>
    <strong>Texto um</strong>
    <p><strong>Texto dois</strong></p>
</div>
```

> [Veja Mais sobre Seletores](http://maujor.com/tutorial/seletores_css21_parte2.php)

---

Logo, seu código deverá ficar assim:

```css
.AlterarCSS > ul > li > span{
    background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="AlterarCSS">

<ul>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
 <li>Nome - <span>Endereço Site<span></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Retire o ">" do CSS tente assim:

```
.AlterarCSS li span{
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Ou faça dessa forma que define os filhos corretamente:

```
.AlterarCSS > ul > li > span{
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente assim:

```
.AlterarCSS ul li span {
    background: yellow; 
}
```